# UITableCell - How do I turn off the selected state of the cell when user navigates back to view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uitableview

I think this is a very common situation, but I can't find how everybody else solves the problem.

I have a UITableView, and when a user taps a cell I push a new view controller (using UINavigationController) on the stack. When the user taps "Back" on the navigation bar, the cell still appears in selected state (i.e. blue background).

I want the background to be blue initially, when the user tapped the cell, but to be turned off when the page is shown again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could deselect the cell before or after you have pushed the new viewcontroller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [aTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // create and push new viewController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do the same thing:

Either Reload the whole Table in View will Appear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [YourTableView reloadData];

}
```

OR Either

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [YourTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Looking at performance wise **second one is best solution** to use.